# Python, accumulate 'itertools.accumulate' object does not support item assignment error

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
diff = [num1-num2 for (num1, num2) in zip(saldo, versamenti)]
iva_a_debito=dict()
iva_a_debito['Iva a debito'] = accumulate(list(diff))

for index, xi in enumerate(iva_a_debito['Iva a debito']):
      if xi < 0 :
          iva_a_debito['Iva a debito'][index] = xi*-1

      else:
           iva_a_debito['Iva a debito'][index] = 0
```

But python give me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'itertools.accumulate' object does not support item assignment
```

Where is the error?

Comment: Post the python traceback with the question. Its rather unsociable to leave out the line with the error even though python gave it to you.

Comment: When an object behaves unexpectedly, maybe its a different object than you think. `print(repr(iva_a_debito['Iva a debito']))` will tell you that its a `itertools.accumulate` object, not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it to a list so you can update it.

`diff` is already a list, you don't need `list(diff)`.

```
iva_a_debito['Iva a debito'] = list(accumulate(diff))
```